# Histogram output not matching input

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

Using `matplotlib`, I'm trying to generate a histogram from a list of values. My output looks like the image in the link shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bedX.png but I know for that none of the values in my list has any value higher than 200, yet the x-axis seems to be higher.

I loaded these values into a list, and in the graph-making function I printed the list just to check and it has the correct values. This is what my code looks like. I have already predefined yax, and I load it into a numpy array.

```
     myarray = np.asarray(yax)
     plt.hist(myarray, bins=100, histtype='stepfilled')
     plt.xlabel("Bins")
     plt.ylabel("Frequency")
     plt.ylim(0,10)
```

My list of values looks something like this (except larger):

```
[38, 45, 43, 36, 35, 32, 31, 32, 31, 35, 38, 35, 33, 33, 36, 36, 35, 36, 39, 41, 38, 37, 39, 39, 38, 35, 34, 35, 38, 42, 37, 37, 34, 34, 29, 30, 37, 33, 31, 32, 35, 36, 41, 46, 44, 46, 42, 38, 41, 40, 38]
```

Here's the actual list which I'm trying to run the program on: http://pastebin.com/U1u6SPsA

Comment: Can you create a small example data set that actually shows the problem?

Comment: Assuming you've omitted "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import numpy as np", the code you've provided produces an accurate histogram. Either there is something wrong with your full "yax" array or there is another detail that is missing here.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your image. By running your code with that array I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/RhHJwaN.png)

Comment: I think I might just not understand how to create a histogram correctly, since my output matches internet examples when I just copy and paste code. So I have a list of size 76000, and I'm loading these values < 200 into it. When I look at the loaded list it appears to be correct and not have any funky values. However, when I run the plt.hist function on it, the general trend appears correct but the x-axis goes from 0-8000 or so, and I know for sure that none of the values of the read values are that high. So basically I'm wondering why the x-axis labels are not matching up with my input.

Comment: Your code is correct -- if your dataset integers are indeed upper-bounded by 200, then it will produce the desired histogram. This being said, one would assume that your array actually contains values > 200. I would take a closer look at the array (e.g. check if len([x for x in yax if x >= 200]) > 0).

Comment: I just uploaded the list that I'm actually running the program on and included it in an edit. I'm almost positive that none of the values are that large. It seems like everything on the x axis is being multiplied by 100 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The histogram is correct. Assuming the full array you have provided is defined as "yax",

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import numpy as np
myarray = np.asarray(yax)
plt.hist(myarray, bins=100, histtype='stepfilled')
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.show() # produces the exact histogram you provided at https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bedX.png

len([x for x in yax if x >= 200])
>>> 102
len([x for x in yax if x >= 1000])
>>> 37
len([x for x in yax if x >= 6000])
>>> 13
len([x for x in yax if x >= 7000])
>>> 3 # matches the height of the histogram for the bin @ 7000
```

The lesson is that visual inspection is not enough -- don't make assumptions about the composition of your dataset.

Comment: Wow I'm garbage. Thanks. I guess I must've screwed up my data set then at some point.

Comment: @user3791562 Everyone makes this mistake at some point, no worries.